# How do I use Perl to parse Twitter XML?

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, twitter

I'm using [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to get the XML file for my [Twitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter) friend's timeline.  (API [here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses-friends_timeline).)

Currently (though I'd be open for more suggestions) I am using Perl to parse the XML.  This is my first time using Perl and I really don't know what I am doing.  Currently this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# use module
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
# Create object.
$xml = new XML::Simple;
# Read XML file.
$data = $xml->XMLin("/tmp/data.xml");
# Print output.
print Dumper($data);
```

Now I want to go through the XML and print out each person's name and then what they tweeted.  Currently I have not found a good guide on Perl's foreach loop when there is a complicated data structure like this one.

How can I achieve this?

(Any other ways to parse the XML in a terminal friendly environment would be nice to know about as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no generic answer - it depends on the content of your data.xml.
For the example on the page you can do the following:

```
foreach my $unode ( values %{$data->{status}} ) {
  print "$unode->{user}->{name} \t $unode->{created_at} \t $unode->{text} \n";
}
```

output:

```
Doug Williams    Tue Apr 07 22:52:51 +0000 2009          At least I can get your humor through tweets. RT @abdur: I don't mean this in a bad way, but genetically speaking your a cul-de-sac.
```

What it does is - it gets the hashref called 'status', dereferences it, and then iterates through its values, which are hashrefs too, assigning each of them to $unode.

You can also look at print Dumper $unode to see what else is available there.
Also note that XML::Simple can be a little tricky in how it parses xml - sometimes you may need to pass in extra parameters to make it create arrays where you want it to - check out the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Simple)

*Programming Perl* Chapter 9 gives you an introduction of the different nested data structures in perl.

Comment: If you follow the link to the API it is there.

Comment: @Naumcho: Don't post links to pirated books.

@Eric: See `perldoc perldsc` for a good discussion of complex data structures in Perl.

Answer (score 12):

Why not use the [Net::Twitter API on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Twitter)?